# Must muslimah wear hijab all time at home if a guest lives there

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, hijab

Muslimaat wear hijab when a non mahram man enter in their home.
However, if a non mahram guest come at home for a long period. Does this means, girls at home must always wear Hijab at home?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes at least in rooms a foreign (non-mahram) guest is present. Note that in the case of a long term guest the husband can't leave this guest alone at home while there's no male mahram present!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes she should. the period how long he is there make no difference.

Comment: Welcome to Islam! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).